What is the median of the minimum or maximum of multiple samples?
Suppose I have a variable with a known distribution, and suppose I sample that variable k times and record the minimum. If I repeat this many times, will the median of the minimum converge to a predictable value, and if so, what is that value?
My instinct tells me that the median will converge to the value for which the cumulative probability is 1/(k+1), but I have not been able to confirm that.
Note that I found a discussion of what the expected value of the maximum would be for samples from a normal distribution: Expected value of maximum of samples from normal distribution. However, that discussion doesn't say anything about the median, which I think should be simpler.

There is a simple formula for the p.d.f.s of those minima and maxima, which could in principle be used to find their medians -- see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155187/proof-for-the-p-d-f-of-minimum-and-maximum-of-a-sample

@jwimberley It's easier and more general to work with the CDF: that gives you an effective formula, not just one in principle.

Let the distribution function of the variable $X$ be $F.$  Given any number $y,$ the chance that the minimum of $k$ iid copies of $X$ exceeds $y$ is the chance that all of those $k$ values exceed $y.$  Because they are independent, this is the product of the individual chances of exceedance, $1-F(y),$ whence
$$\Pr(\min(X_1,\ldots, X_k)\gt y) = (1-F(y))^k.$$
Thus, the distribution function of the minimum is
$$F_{(k)}(y) = \Pr(\min(X_1,\ldots, X_k)\le y) = 1-(1-F(y))^k.$$
To find a median, look for a $y$ for which the the graph of $F_{(k)}$ crosses the value $1/2:$ that is, look for a solution to
$$\frac{1}{2} = 1 - (1 - F(y))^k$$
(or, possibly, the right hand side could exceed $1/2$ but would be strictly less than $1/2$ for any smaller $y$).
Such a solution would satisfy
$$F(y) = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/k}.$$
That is,

Any median of the minimum of $k$ iid random values is a $1 - 2^{-1/k}$ quantile.

Whenever $k \gt 1,$ $1-2^{-1/k} \ne 1/(k+1).$
